# Floating button in Community page

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, aura, community-builder, digital-experience

I am trying to figure out the way, how to add a floating button( which stays always in the same position on the page) To our community page.

In this case, it's just a simple button to navigate to the top of the page(when Knowledge article is long)
I don't have problem with the button functionality itself. i just don't know, if there is a way, to position it(always bottom right corner of the window). As both LWC or Aura are restricted to their own container. so the position is fixed on the page(not on the window.

I am using build your own tamplate.

Comment: Hi MatejN, Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: i just answered the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is to create custom layout, where you put the button directly to the component and use display Flex - sticky to fix the position.

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:themeLayout">
    <aura:attribute name="search" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="profileMenu" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="themeHero" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="navMenu" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="smallLogo" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="newHeader" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="themeFooter" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
    <div class="main">
     
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical">
            
            <div class="slds-col slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-center slds-grid_align-spread slds-grid alternative-header">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12">
                    <div class="logoContainer"></div>
             </div>
               <div class="slds-col slds-size_5-of-12">
                    {!v.navMenu}
                </div>
                    <div class="notifications slds-col slds-col_bump-left">
                        <forceCommunity:notifications/>
                    </div>
                    
                 <div class="slds-col">
                    {!v.profileMenu}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
                {!v.themeHero}
            </div>
         **<div class="slds-col">
            {!v.body}
             <div class="sticky"> <c:backToTheTopButton name="Earthling" /></div>
        </div>**
        <div class="slds-col footer">
            {!v.themeFooter}
          
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
</aura:component>
```

Use css to style the component.. this is just for my usage

```
.THIS .main {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.THIS .sticky{
    position: sticky;
    bottom:40px;
    margin-left: 90%;
    justify-content: end;
}
```

and of course style the component itself:

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
```

Read on custom theme layouts [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm)!

and Flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)!

I was trying to avoid custom layouts as I am new to coding and development. But it wasn't that hard.